# ForFiles not working for recursive folder with dynamic folder name

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, dynamic, special-folders

I wanna use forfiles to delete files older than 92 days, but the code seems to be breaking. 
I have a dynamic folder name.

```
for /d %X in (e:\local\test\backups\s?????pbx\) do forfiles /p %X /m *.cab /c "cmd /c del @path" /d -92
```

I couldn't figure out where I am going wrong. Is there any other way to achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `?` isn't a wildcard in batch.

Comment: @SomethingDark why wouldn't it?

Comment: @ths What, why isn't `?` a wildcard in batch? Because the people at Microsoft decided to make `*` the wildcard. You'd have to ask them for more details.

Comment: that's just not true. a ? is a wildcard for a single character.

Comment: Well look at that; so it is. Still, you can't guarantee that the folder will have five characters that can be wildcards, so using `*` is still better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows commands only support wildcards in the terminal node of a path - It will not find paths that appear anywhere before the last `\`.

The solution for your problem is really simple :-) Just remove the final `\`

```
for /d %X in (e:\local\test\backups\s?????pbx) do forfiles /p %X /m *.cab /c "cmd /c del @path" /d -92
```

Answer (score 0):

Batch uses `*` as a wildcard character. Try this:

```
for /d %X in (e:\local\test\backups\s*pbx\) do forfiles /p %X /m *.cab /c "cmd /c del @path" /d -92
```

Comment: I can see what's supposed to be happening, but what is actually happening?

Comment: It was suppose to delete the files older than 92 days from directory e:\local\test\backups having subfolders "s*pbx".
But I dont even see the echo command working instead of the delete command

Comment: Just to be sure, you're running this on the command line instead of via a batch script, right? Because if this is inside a script, you need to use `%%X` instead of `%X`.

Comment: try running `for /D %X in (E:\local\test\backups\s*pbx\) do echo %X` and see if anything comes up. There may be an issue with the outer `for` loop.